# fill combobox at runtime jsp

Tags: jsp, combobox, runtime

i have 1 combobox in jsp which is filled with value from sql db on load of form

```
  <td width="150">
      <%
         Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
         Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:mydsn");;
          Statement s = cn.createStatement();

           ResultSet re = s.executeQuery("select distinct From1 from station");
       %>

        <select>
        <%
         while (re.next()) {
            String un = re.getString("From1");
         %>
         <option value="<%= un%>"><%= un%></option>
        <%
        }
         %>
         </select>
</td>
```

i have another combobox below it, i want it to be filled on the basis of selected value of 1st combobox...plz help with code

Comment: Scriptlets are obsolete, please use the sql-jslt style. stackoverflow.com/questions/7697041/how-to-use-jstl-sql-tag

Answer (score 0):

First of all I prefer JQuery framework for this.

Well, you should use AJAX, pass the seleted value to an URL which points to a Java-Servlet and execute logic there.

```
$.ajax({
 data: 'value=option',
 type: 'POST',
 url: 'processDataServlet.jsp'
 success: function (data) {
   $('td').append(data);
 } 
});
```

Otherwise you can use an simple JavaScript "if" condition if you have the data for the condition already loaded:

```
<option onSelected="checkCondition($(this))" value="...." .... />


function checkCondition(var element) {
 var val = element.val();
 if(val = "myValue") {
   alert("Value selected");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this sounds like a one-page-wizard.

Assuming you have this constalation:

```
<form method="get" name="blah">
   <select name="first">...</select>
   <select name="second">...</select>
</form>
```

So there are three states of the form:

1. Empty (nothing selected)
2. Half (First dropdown filled)
3. Full (First and second Dropdown filled)

The first Phase is identified by no-request-params.

The second Phase is identified by the existance of request-param "first".

The third, the Full state, is identified by the existance of the request-params "first" and "second".

The solution is easy:

1. Duplicate your code
2. Name the selects "first" and "second" in example.
3. Around the second part, encapsul a "if(request.getParameter("first")!=null) {" and "}"
4. Add a javascript-listener to the first select like

   ```
   onchange="document.forms.blah.submit()";
   ```